# Problem with resizable div and contenteditable header

Tags: html, css

I have one problem. I have resizable section and contenteditable header of that section. When i am typing something in contenteditable it works perfectly - section width is resizing, but when i resize section by button and then type something in header - contenteditable doesn't resize div. How can I repair it? My code:

**HTML**

```
       <section class="note">
            <h1 class="noteHeader">
                <span class="headerText" contenteditable="true" max="50">Title</span>
                <img class="deleteNote" src="images/delete.png" alt="Delete">
            </h1>
            <textarea class="noteText" rows="6"></textarea>
       </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.note {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    border: 20px groove rgb(233, 235, 234);
    background-color: rgb(240, 255, 255);
    min-width: 10%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 15%;
    resize: both;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
     z-index: 10;
}
.noteHeader {
    cursor: text;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 24%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0; 
    text-align: left;
    font-size: calc(1vh + 1vw);
    outline: none;
}
.headerText {
    outline: none;
    padding-right: 20%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.deleteNote {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: calc(1vh + 1vw);
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: "...resize section by button..." - what button? Could you please include that, along with whatever javascript goes with it?

Comment: well, i didn't correctly named it, it is a "button" which comes with "resize:both" option